# SAS: how to check if the same variable from two datasets are different?

Tags: sas

I have two datasets DA and DB, both contains the variable ssn and are sorted by ssn. How do I check whether DA contains some ssn that is not listed in DB and vice versa?  I considered proc compare but it seems that the compare procedure can only compare the observations at the same position. For example, if

```
data DA;
    input ssn &;
    datalines;
    100-00-0001
    100-00-0003
    100-00-0004
;


data DB;
    input ssn &;
    datalines;
    100-00-0001
    100-00-0002
    100-00-0003
;
```

Then the results of compare will list 100-00-0003 and 100-00-0004 although both datasets contain 100-00-0003. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Merge the two datasets together by SSN and output to different datasets, e.g.

```
data A_only B_only;
  merge DA(in = a keep = SSN) 
        DB(in = b keep = SSN);
  by SSN;
  if a and not(b) then output a_only;
  if b and not(a) then output b_only;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ID` statement in PROC COMPARE.  Untested:

```
proc compare base=da compare=db listobs ;
  id SSN ;
run ;
```

There are options to output to a dataset as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use proc sql:

```
proc sql;
    select * from DA where ssn not in(select ssn from DB);
    select * from DB where ssn not in(select ssn from DA);
quit;
```